# Handle ajax Requests in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am working on one web application which is Single Page Application.

In that my front end will be on server and back end will be on other server.

So for each add/edit/delete/fetch operation , i need to call an Ajax request to the Back End.

There are plenty of ajax requests till now.So is there any way to handle them. I mean in angular js is there any way to do so?

FYI. I am bit new in the Angular Js.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to best structure your code, so you could easily add new HTTP requests to your client, or how to handle numerous HTTP requests in AngularJS, using batches?

Comment: $http, $resource services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create factories using ngResource https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource or individually using make individual requests using $http service provider https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http. I would recommend to go for factories method. You will find this link useful if you are looking for ward to experiment it https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/

Comment: I tried https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/ link. I have created factories using ngResource for two end points initially. I will use more as application progresses. Thanks :)